# Clicking one panel opens other panel tabs - photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

When I click on the layers panel it opens additional tabs of other panels as well. I have tried to click and drag them back to the side panel but when I click the layers panel again they still appear. Have also tried to collapse them back into the panel with the double arrow icon on the top right corner and still happens. I am guessing this might have to be adjusted in the preferences?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group panels so they will open as tabs when one of them is clicked.

When you drag and drop those panel icons you can either drag them onto another panel to add them to the same group or you can create a separate panel by dragging it at the bottom of the bar (or between two icons).

[image]